# Red to dotnet or java android: .Net -> Red (Not Implemented)

Tags: red

On https://github.com/red/red/tree/master/bridges it says not implemented, will it be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [official news](https://www.red-lang.org/2018/04/sneak-peek-at-red-on-android.html) before raising such questions (or rather consider to use Gitter [community chat](https://gitter.im/red/red/welcome)).

Android bridge is currently developed in a private branch and will go public in [0.7.1 release](https://trello.com/b/FlQ6pzdB/red-tasks-overview).

.NET bridge in the master branch is a PoC; there are [Mono bridge](https://github.com/iceflow19/red-mono) and [.NET bindings](https://github.com/koba-yu/LibRedSharp) available from community members, but official CLR support, as far as I know, is not planned in the near future, and will likely take a high priority in post-1.0 roadmap.

Comment: I'm not sure if existence of the answer somewhere else on the internet is an argument against asking the question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For me it indicates that no research effort was applied - all answers are readily available in public, official resources (such as Red blog and roadmap) and shouldn't be terribly hard to come by.

Comment: red is not well indexed in google and I'm not capable of reading in mind yet ;) but thanks for the links.